# Architecture Question - User Driven Resource Allocation

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, containers

I am working on a SaaS application built on Azure AKS. Users will connect to a web frontend, and depending on their selection, will deploy containers on demand for their respective Organization. There will be a backend API layer that will connect to the Kubernetes API for the deployment of different YAML configurations.

Users will select a predefined container (NodeJs container app), and behind the scenes that container will be created from a template and a URL provided to the user to consume that REST API resource via common HTTP verbs.

I read the following blurb on the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/):

> You'll rarely create individual Pods directly in Kubernetes—even singleton Pods. This is because Pods are designed as relatively ephemeral, disposable entities. When a Pod gets created (directly by you, or indirectly by a controller), the new Pod is scheduled to run on a Node in your cluster. The Pod remains on that node until the Pod finishes execution, the Pod object is deleted, the Pod is evicted for lack of resources, or the node fails.

I am thinking that that each "organization account" in my application should deploy containers that are allocated a shared context constrained to a Pod, with multiple containers spun up for each "resource" request. This is because, arguably, an Organization would prefer that their "services" were unique to their Organization and not shared with the scope of others. Assume that namespace, service, or pod name is not a concern as each will be named on the backend with a GUID or similar unique identifier.

Questions:

1. Is this an appropriate use of Pods and Services in Kubernetes?
2. Will scaling out mean that I add nodes to the cluster to support the
   maximum constraint of 110 Pods / node?
3. Should I isolate these data services / pods from the front-end to its own dedicated cluster, then add a cluster when (if) maximum Node count of 15,000 is reached?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I added this detail. I am using Azure / AKS. I noticed that there is an auto-scaling node pool, so I expect nodes will scale out automatically as pods reach their upper limit.

Comment: Did you try to deploy yet, or is it a more theoretical question?

Comment: Theoretical question on the use of Pods for production scenarios. If I want to isolate user owned resources, do I isolate to a pod or create a deployment template.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have a look at [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

A container is in a pod.

A pod is in a deployment

A service exposes a deployment.

Comment: So, you mean when I want to spin up a new container inside of an existing Pod I would modify a deployment config?

Comment: You said "when I want to spin up a new container inside of an existing Pod". I don't understand this. Pods are created once, they don't get updated. Maybe this helps: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment